# How to install windows 7 on HP Pavilion h8-1234 PC with missing Hp DVD A DH16ACSH SCSI CdRom driver?

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, dvd, hp-pavilion

I am currently attempting to re-install windows 7 on my HP Pavilion h8-1234 computer and I need help in identifying what drivers am I missing for the windows re-installation process.

I downloaded windows 7 from http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-59465.iso and burned it as an image to a DVD-R using ImgBurn software. The windows installer menu displays the following issue with missing drivers:

```
Load Driver
A required CD/DVD drive device driver is missing. If you have a driver floppy disk, CD, DVD, or USB flash drive, please insert it now.
Note: If the Windows installation media is in the CD/DVD drive, you can safely remove it for this step.
```

I identified the DVD drive as a Hp DVD A DH16ACSH SCSI CdRom and downloaded the corresponding driver from http://www.driverscape.com/download/hp-dvd-a--dh16acsh-scsi-cdrom-device unto my usb. I picked the following driver version to download :

```
Driver Version: 6.1.7600.16385
Release Date: 2006-06-21
File Size: 77.34K
Supported OS: Windows 7 64bit
```

I plugged the usb into the HP Pavilion h8-1234 during the windows installation process and navigated through the folder browser to select the Hp DVD A DH16ACSH SCSI CdRom driver to be used to run the windows installation prcoess. Below is the folder browse to get to the Hp DVD A DH16ACSH SCSI CdRom driver :

```
Computer
Removable Disk (C:)
cdrom.inf_amd64_neutral_8363d00ecae4322d
```

I received the following message from the windows installer :

```
No new devices could be found. Make sure the driver files are correct and located on the driver installation media.
```

I navigated the HP website, but could not find the Hp DVD A DH16ACSH SCSI CdRom driver. Does any know where I can download the required Hp DVD A DH16ACSH SCSI CdRom driver? Is it possible to just copy it from the windows operating system instead? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the driver is not the actual problem. Quoting a related Microsoft KB article:

> #### Cause
>
> This issue occurs for one of the following reasons:
>
> - The installation DVD is removed during the setup process.
> - A low-quality DVD was used to create the installation DVD.
> - The speed at which the installation DVD was burned was too fast.
> - The DVD drive cannot read the media.
> - The ISO file is corrupted.
>
> #### Resolution
>
> To resolve this issue, use one of the following methods, as appropriate for your situation:
>
> - Burn the installation DVD at a slower speed.
> - Use a better quality DVD to create the installation DVD.
> - Update the BIOS firmware for your DVD drive.
> - Use the [Windows 7 USB/DVD Download tool](http://images2.store.microsoft.com/prod/clustera/framework/w7udt/1.0/en-us/Windows7-USB-DVD-tool.exe) to create a bootable USB flash drive, and then use the USB flash drive to install Windows.
>
> <sub>Source: ["A required CD/DVD drive device driver is missing" or "A media driver your computer needs is missing" error message when you install Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2755139/en-us)</sub>

Before troubleshooting this issue, check whether the ISO file is corrupted. Here are the basic details of the file you downloaded, straight from [MSDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Developer_Network):

> #### Windows 7 Ultimate with Service Pack 1 (x64) - DVD (English)
>
> This media refresh includes the installation hotfix described in [KB Article 2534111](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2534111/en-us). No other changes have been made to the product.
>
> **Release Date:** 5/12/2011
> **Size:** 3167 MB
> **SHA1:** 36AE90DEFBAD9D9539E649B193AE573B77A71C83
>
> <sub>Source: [MSDN Subscriber Downloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/downloads/#searchTerm=&ProductFamilyId=350&Languages=en&FileExtensions=.iso&PageSize=10&PageIndex=0&FileId=0)</sub>

### Further reading

- ["A required CD/DVD drive device driver is missing" or "A media driver your computer needs is missing" error message when you install Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2755139/en-us)
- [How to compute the MD5 or SHA-1 cryptographic hash values for a file](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/889768/en-us)

Comment: How do i format a usb for windows installation from my linux computer?

Comment: @linuxfreebird Here's a guide that should get you started: [Create A Bootable Windows 7 USB Drive From Linux (Tested On Ubuntu)](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/create-bootable-windows-7-usb-drive.html)